# Bilinear, inner product, transpose and derivative

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, let $G: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$G(x)= \langle Ax,x\rangle.$$

Show that $D G(a)(h)=\langle(A+A^T)h,a\rangle$.

I proved before that $Dg(a)(h)=f(a,h)+f(h,a)$ if $f$ is bilinear and $g(x)=f(x,x)$.
I know that is the hint for this problem but I cannot see how these are connected and I have no idea where the transpose comes from in this question.

Could anyone show in detail how to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the function $G$?

Comment: G(x)=<Ax,x> I don't why it did not show in the question

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is the composition of $x\rightarrow A(x)$ and the bilinear function $(x,y)\rightarrow <x,y>$ so:

$DG_a(h) =<A(a),h>+<A(h),a>=<a,A^T(h)>+<A(h),a>=<(A+A^T)(h),a>$.